# BigCommerce serving preview images for product options?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

My product has multiple options and each option has an image, but BigCommerce returns a link for the image like this:
[https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-2zrsm6mrhd/images/stencil/{:size}/attribute_value_images/17384.preview.jpg?t=1618265813](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-2zrsm6mrhd/images/stencil/%7B:size%7D/attribute_value_images/17384.preview.jpg?t=1618265813)

as you can see it's a `preview.jpg` file which is compressed and has lower quality, even if set I the size really high it's still a bit pixelated. How can I get the original quality image? and not the preview one?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kevin have you tried uploading using the REST API using Postman as the method of calling your images? I.E.  POST [https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/catalog/products/{product_id}/variants/{variant_id}/image](https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/%7Bstore_hash%7D/v3/catalog/products/%7Bproduct_id%7D/variants/%7Bvariant_id%7D/image)  and then running in the body {
"image_url": "string"
} Calling the Original quality image url in the string. This might avoid the need of any compressed images being called and alleviate your pixilation issues.

Comment: no I don't do any http request, because I'm uploading the images for the product options. So basically when I create a new product option (swatch) BG is compressing them, how to I get the original version?

Comment: Try updating the specific [product option variant](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/ae07dc0a38068-update-a-product-variant-option) to call the image_url string with the original image.